# Prove that $f_n$ = $\frac{x}{1+n^2x^2}$ uniformly converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Prove that $f_n$ = $\frac{x}{1+n^2x^2}$ uniformly converges.

I know that the limit function would be $f(x)$ = 0 but I'm getting stuck on how to prove that with the definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: On what domain? Uniform convergence is defined in some set, maybe $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

From the AM-GM inequality, $1+n^2x^2\ge 2n|x|$.  Thus,

$$\left|\frac{x}{1+n^2x^2}\right|\le \frac1{2n}$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*  Try finding the maximum of $f_n(x)$, and using the definition of uniform convergence.  Be sure to consider which interval you're working on.